# How to get first (last modified) folder name in given path in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

How to get first (last modified) folder name from `\\demo\Test\test1\`?
If the first folder is `test-new_20170908.2` how do I get `test-new_20170908.2` and only the `20170908.2` part?

This is what I've done so far:

```
@echo off
set MYDIR=\\demo\Test\test1\
set MYDIR1=%MYDIR:~0,-1%
for %%f in (%MYDIR1%) do set myfolder=%%~nxf
echo %myfolder% > folderPath.txt
```

This code gives me `test1` but I want the very first folder name inside given path and this does not work as per my specification.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by first folder: sorted alphabetical by name a before z?

Comment: @AndreKampling from Path `\\demo\Test\test1\` in this path the first folder and that is always updated by data and time so which ever is modified recently that will be the first.  in this case **test-new_20170908.2** and I wanted the folder name and in that wants to use only from the folder name **20170908.2**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following script will sort all directories (`/a:d`) under `demo\Test\test1` by the last write date (`/o:-d /tw`) and just save the second token of the name separated by `_`: `name_date` which is `date`.

**Batch script:**

```cmd
@echo off

set "MYDIR=demo\Test\test1"

rem sort directories by date (last write)
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir "%MYDIR%" /a:d /o:-d /tw /b') do (
   rem use second token after _ in name
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ('echo %%f') do ( set "myfolder=%%a" )
   goto :found
)

:found

echo %myfolder%
```

**Output:**

> ```cmd
> 20170908.2
> ```

---

Command reference links from [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/):

- [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [goto](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [rem](https://ss64.com/nt/rem.html)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set MYDIR=\\demo\Test\test1\
set MYDIR1=%MYDIR:~0,-1%
SET "mydir=U:\sourcedir\"
FOR /d %%a IN ("%mydir%\*") DO SET "myfolder=%%~nxa"&GOTO found
:found
echo %myfolder%

GOTO :EOF
```

I overrode you setting of `mydir` to a directory that is more convenient in my system.

Look for all of the directories (`for /d`) matching the supplied mask (the `\` here makes it irrelevant whether you include a terminal `\` in the value of `mydir` (my preference is to omit that terminal `\`) then treat the returned directoryname as a filename and select the name and extension using the `for` name-partitioning operators; assign the result to the variable and force exit from the `for` with a `goto` once the first assignment as occurred.